# jquery not working with google apps script

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, google-apps-script

I am trying to populate a drop down list using the data stored in a spreadsheet so the user can make the selection and some action can be performed after that.

I try but cannot get the data to be populated in the list box.

Regards,

Code.gs

```
function doGet() {
  var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index');

  var htmlOutput = template.evaluate()
                   .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.NATIVE);

  return htmlOutput;
}

function getClients() {
  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1eFZ1Qmw9ycPn7kXZX9DhA8m5kUxXS8KW4k9McvAaXpo");
  var sheet = doc.getActiveSheet();
  var allClients = sheet.getRange(3, 3, sheet.getLastRow(),1).getValues();
  var clients = [];
  for (i=0;i<allClients.length-1;i++){
      clients.push(allClients[i][0]);
      Logger.log("Client "+i+clients[i]);


  }
  return(clients);
}
```

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.3/jquery.mobile.min.css" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.3/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script>

function addClients(clients){
  $('#customer').empty();
  for (var i in clients) {
    $('#customer').append('<option>'+clients[i]+'</option>');
    $('#customer').trigger("chosen:updated");
  }
});

$('document').ready(function(){
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(addClients).getClients();
});
</script>
</head>

<div>
<h3><b>Client:</b></h3>

<select name="customer" id="customer" data-native-menu="true" data-role="none">
    <option> ---- Choose a client ----</option>
</select>
</div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the new IFRAME instead of NATIVE.

`var htmlOutput = template.evaluate()
                   .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);`

If you start getting `undefined` functions in Jquery, remove the `.min`.

Comment: I changed to IFRAME, but still the same result. a blank select box.

Comment: I tried all other options by defining array in the function itself, but the listbox does not get populated. The function is not being executed at all.

Comment: If this answer solved your question you can mark it as so, so people know it has been closed. If you think this answer what ellaborated, you can upvote it.